# zoom over specific route google map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, marker, polyline

[image][image][image: below is screen shot @antonio what i get after removing line]

I have a list of random latitude and longitude points and I am drawing a route between them. My question is how to bound this route within google map I made below utility method

```
public static void drawRouteIntoMap(final List<? extends MapHelper> position, final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    /*List<MapHelper> position = new ArrayList<MapHelper>();
    for (int i = lastPosition; i < maps.size(); i++) {
        position.add(maps.get(i));
    }*/
    if (position.size() > 0 && Validator.isNotNull(googleMap)) {
        googleMap.clear();
        List<PolylineOptions> polylineOptionses = new ArrayList<PolylineOptions>();
        PolylineOptions option = null;
        Boolean lastPause = null;
        for (MapHelper map : position) {
            if (map.isPause()) {
                if (Validator.isNull(lastPause) || !lastPause) {
                    option = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.rgb(255, 0, 155)).geodesic(true);
                    polylineOptionses.add(option);
                }
                option.add(new LatLng(map.getLatitude(), map.getLongitude()));
            } else {
                if (Validator.isNull(lastPause) || lastPause) {
                    option = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.rgb(0, 179, 253)).geodesic(true);
                    polylineOptionses.add(option);
                }
                option.add(new LatLng(map.getLatitude(), map.getLongitude()));
            }
            lastPause = map.isPause();
        }
        for (PolylineOptions options : polylineOptionses) {
            googleMap.addPolyline(options);
        }
        if(Validator.isNotNull(option)){
            //List<LatLng> points = option.getPoints();
            final LatLngBounds.Builder mapBounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

            googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapLoaded() {
                    LatLng startPoint = new LatLng(position.get(0).getLatitude(), position.get(0).getLongitude());
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(startPoint).title("start").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
                    mapBounds.include(startPoint);
                    LatLng endPoint = new LatLng(position.get(position.size() - 1).getLatitude(), position.get(position.size() - 1).getLongitude());
                    mapBounds.include(endPoint);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(endPoint).title("finish").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mapBounds.build(), 10));
                   /* googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mapBounds.build(), 10));
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());*/

                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

here last pause is boolean indicating whether it is paused point for indicating red color polyline.

but it is not working.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Yvette i want to show this whole route in given mapview with lite mode such that entire route is clearly get visible with start point,end point and polyline between this two marker

Comment: @Yvette i have uploaded screen shot,there is list of such items

Comment: @Yvette yes i want to show this different routes withinn this map area

Comment: Showing all points that were added to a map. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671790/android-plotting-gps-coordinate-on-custom-map/19850330#19850330

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Try implementing this way**

```
/**
 * Zooms a Route (given a List of LalLng) at the greatest possible zoom level.
 *
 * @param googleMap: instance of GoogleMap
 * @param lstLatLngRoute: list of LatLng forming Route
 */
public void zoomRoute(GoogleMap googleMap, List<LatLng> lstLatLngRoute) {

    if (googleMap == null || lstLatLngRoute == null || lstLatLngRoute.isEmpty()) return;

    LatLngBounds.Builder boundsBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (LatLng latLngPoint : lstLatLngRoute)
        boundsBuilder.include(latLngPoint);

    int routePadding = 100;
    LatLngBounds latLngBounds = boundsBuilder.build();

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, routePadding));
}
```

**UPDATE**

After looking at the image, there are layouts above map. So it would require you to set **Variable Padding**. You can do it as

```
googleMap.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Note: While setting variable padding, you can initialize `routePadding = 0`;
In your case, approximations are: `left = right = 10`, `bottom=100`, `top=200`. Once set, you can calibrate'em as per your requirement.

`Recommendation: You can calculate the height of those (top and bottom) layouts in pixels and then set padding accordingly.`

Comment: why you chosse padding value of 100?

Comment: Padding is used so that the Markers (if existent at points) don't get clipped during zoom and the Route doesn't touch the Map Edges. You can set your own Custom Value (e.g., the Height or Width of the Marker Image). It could even be 0 if you wish the Route should touch the Map Edges.

Comment: i have tried your solution but still in some route marker is get clipped i can upload screen shot

Comment: Try increasing the Padding >= 2 * Height of Marker (in pixels)

Comment: currently  i am using BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED) this method for marker

Comment: do you know  what will be default height because in documentation it is saying about constant only

Comment: I don't have any idea about that but as a work-around you can continue increasing the padding until your Markers are not clipped. Also, did the above solution helped in any way??

Comment: it is working but still for some routes marker or route is 60% visible. so can u please help on calculating padding dynamically.@Rishabh Dutt Sharma i uploaded screen shot that i got after trying this solution (padding values are : 15(Left), 205(Top), 10(Right), 110(Bottom))

Answer (score 7):

The reason, why zooming in is not working might be because map has not been inflated yet at the time of calling the method:

[`moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate))

Try adding [`ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) to the map:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = googleMap.getViewTreeObserver();
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener globalLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            googleMap.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            googleMap.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mapBounds.build(), 10));
    }
};
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(globalLayoutListener);
```

If the method above does not work `GoogleMap` has it's own listener for layout, you might use that:

```
googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mapBounds.build(), 10));
        googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
    }
});
```

However, as of play-services-maps 9.4.0 version of the API the method above is deprecated. Use one of:

- [`GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener)
- [`GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener)
- [`GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener)

Answer (score 4):

You need to include all the points that form the polyline into your `mapBounds` object.

Also, you are updating the camera using `animateCamera` and then you are moving it using `moveCamera`. This second camera update overrides the first one. Just remove the line

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
```

This line is also innecesary (you don't need to move and animate the camera, just one of them):

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mapBounds.build(), 10));
```

If you need to zoom out a bit your map you can play with the padding parameter of the `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds` method.

Comment: i have uploaded screen shot see markers are not displaying properly this is justone route there can be different other routes like this

Comment: How are you drawing your route? Could you post an example?

Comment: please check it i uploaded method

Comment: You need to add all the points that form the polyline to your `mapBounds`

Comment: see i uploaded image in this i have included all the points in mapbounds forming polyline. still end marker is not visible

Comment: OK, now the problem is that you need to increase the padding of the `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds` to fit the Marker that lays on the top

Comment: so how can i determine padding every time depand on route path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124649/discussion-between-hardik-mehta-and-antonio).

Answer (score 3):

I implemented a similar solution to @rishabh-dutt-sharma with a couple of twists:

- First of all, before zooming check if the points are already inside the view. If they are, do not change it. This means less unneeded changes in the UI for the user.
- Second, a special case is when there is just one point. This is useful when showing a list of markers, and maybe is not needed in your particular case. The reason of why is this useful is because in the case of single point, the zoom usually is increased to the maximum, and usually this is too much.

This is the code (adapted from my original code, I hope there are no typos):

```
    public void zoomRoute(GoogleMap googleMap, List<LatLng> lstLatLngRoute) {

        if (googleMap == null || lstLatLngRoute == null || lstLatLngRoute.isEmpty()) return;

        LatLngBounds currentLatLongBounds =
                googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
        boolean updateBounds = false;

        for (LatLng latLng : lstLatLngRoute) {
            if (!currentLatLongBounds.contains(latLng)) {
                updateBounds = true;
            }
        }

        if (updateBounds) {

            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate;

            if (lstLatLngRoute.size() == 1) {

                LatLng latLng = lstLatLngRoute.iterator().next();
                cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);

            } else {

                LatLngBounds.Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
                for (LatLng latLng : lstLatLngRoute) {
                    builder.include(latLng);
                }
                LatLngBounds latLongBounds = builder.build();

                cameraUpdate =
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLongBounds, MAP_ZOOM_PADDING);

            }

            try {
                googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, MAP_CAMERA_ANIMATION_DURATION_IN_MILLIS,
                        new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                            }
                        });
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                // Ignore it. We're just being a bit lazy, as this exception only happens if
                // we try to animate the camera before the map has a size
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what will be the value of this constants for padding & animation duration second

Comment: Padding is the number of pixels, I use 90dp for density independence, which you can store in a dimen resource or convert from a constant with a routine like this: `public static float dipToPixels(Context context, float dipValue) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dipValue, metrics);
    }`. Animation duration is in milliseconds, I use 500 for fast and smooth animations.

Answer (score 3):

you can do one thing, find out the distance between 2 latitude and longitude and make check over distance that you got.See,how it work .
It's a trick it might useful for you.

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(reachLocationLatLng));
if (dist > 2 && dist <= 5) {
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13.0f));
mapZoomLevel = 12;
} else if (dist > 5 && dist <= 10) {
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12.0f));
mapZoomLevel = 11;
} else if (dist > 10 && dist <= 20) {
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11.0f));
mapZoomLevel = 11;
} else if (dist > 20 && dist <= 40) {
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10.0f));
mapZoomLevel = 10;
} else if (dist > 40 && dist < 100) {
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(9.0f));
mapZoomLevel = 9;
} else if (dist > 100 && dist < 200) {
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8.0f));
mapZoomLevel = 8;
} else if (dist > 200 && dist < 400) {
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(7.0f));
mapZoomLevel = 7;
} else if (dist > 400 && dist < 700) {
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(6.0f));
mapZoomLevel = 7;
} else if (dist > 700 && dist < 1000) {
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5.0f));
mapZoomLevel = 6;
} else if (dist > 1000) {
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(4.0f));
mapZoomLevel = 5;
} else {
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14.0f));
mapZoomLevel = 14;
}
```

Thanks hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(endPoint,zoomLevel));
```

Try it if it helps you

Comment: what zoomlevel shold i set

Comment: you can try for any number 10, 12, 15 and check the changes

Comment: after all these lines i add this or at any other place?

Comment: googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mapBounds.build(), 10)); replace this line

Comment: which values you have tried and what you can see as output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124022/discussion-between-hardik-mehta-and-preetika-kaur).

Comment: This wont help you when your source and destination are varying

Answer (score 0):

How I did it.

[Android - plotting gps coordinate on custom map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671790/android-plotting-gps-coordinate-on-custom-map/19850330#19850330)

Yes you can draw points that aren't on the visible map. Get around this by setting up a LatLngBounds. Then display the map for the LatLngBounds. You can also move the map to display the LatLngBounds. There's nothing tricky here no tangents or slopes or hyperbolic curvature of the earth. All that's taken care of by the point which is in degrees so don't over think your solution. If you turn the map the points will turn with it. So add your points to the map find the bounds and tilt the camera. Tilt the camera back and all the points will still be on screen! This will get you started with the all the points on the screen.

Same as the samples get a reference to a google map.

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
// Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
// map.

if (mMap == null) {
    // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
    // mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
    // // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.

    // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    // use the settings maptype

    // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
    if (mMap != null) {
        setUpMap();
    }
}
}
```

Let's get started finding the boundry of the map.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
A field for LatLngBounds and a LatLngBounds.Builder

private LatLngBounds bounds;
private LatLngBounds.Builder myLatLngBuilder;
initialize the LatLngBounds.Builder

myLatLngBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for each point on your map.

LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
myLatLngBuilder.include(myLatLng);
Then when your finished adding points build your boundary.

bounds = myLatLngBuilder.build();
Now I have the bounds of all the points on my map and I can display just that area of the map. This code I lifted from the map samples.

final View mapView = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map).getView();
    if (mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
        mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    // We use the new method when supported
                    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                    // We check which build version we are using.
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            mapView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        } else {
                            mapView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                .newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50));
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very late to answer 
 try with this shortest way

First of All get your current location latlongs then your write code for your destination lat longs then calculate distance between your current location and destination location with this code

```
private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
  double theta = lon1 - lon2;
  double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
  dist = Math.acos(dist);
  dist = rad2deg(dist);
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
   return (dist);
}
private double deg2rad(double deg) {
  return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}
private double rad2deg(double rad) {
  return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```

- you can never get same lat longs data because of GPS count 95 meters from your current location to display current location pin or lat long data.
  either you are same location you can never find exact lat long data this must be differ in points so thats by you need to get distance your current location to your fix lat long data points.
- when ever you find "**distance**" from your destination points to current lat long then fire this code to animate camera and zoom.

  ```
  map.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(xxxx,xxxx),21));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Probably This would be most simple solution for above mentioned problem, It worked for me very well.

Add all the waypoints to the target under GoogleMapOptions:camera, then it will automatically set the zoom and center the map with respect to Polyline( given Route).

```
loadMap() {

let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
  camera: {
    target: this.wayPoints,
    zoom: 25,
    tilt: 30
  }
};

this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);
this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Map is ready!');


   this.map.addPolyline({
      points:this.wayPoints,
      color:'#586bff',
      width: 8,
      geodesic:true,
    });
});
}
```

The waypoints( this.wayPoints ) should be in this format:

```
[{lat: 52.33806, lng: 8.61179},
{lat: 52.33812, lng: 8.61185},
{lat: 52.33812, lng: 8.61186},
{lat: 52.33812, lng: 8.61188}]
```